# Create new instance of MailAddress using stored variables instead of strings for parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, parameters, instantiation

Could you help me understand why this isn't working? Because I'm unable to create a new MailAddress object using variables in place of the strings that are normally assigned in the *Display* and *Address* parameters.

If the following code is used then the email goes through fine from "The Example Sender" (i.e., the *Display* parameter) whose email address is "examplesender@mail.com" (i.e., the *Address* parameter):

```
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress("examplesender@mail.com", "The Example Sender");
```

However if I want to update the From Address using input that's stored in a variable it no longer works:

```
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromDisplayName, fromEmailAddress);
```

I'm unable to go in and replace the *Display* and *Address* parameters since they're read-only. So I can't do the following:

```
            myMessage.From.DisplayName = fromDisplayName;
            myMessage.From.Address = fromEmailAddress;
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on how I can create a new MailAddresss using variables?

Comment: When you say "using input that's stored in a variable it no longer works", can you clarify what you mean by "no longer works".  Does it not compile? Is it giving you some sort of error?  Is there an exception thrown?

Comment: It compiles and runs but I get an error when that part of the code gets called. Normally it goes through fine and the email is sent. Now the email is no longer being sent out.

Comment: It would help if you would tell us the error you are getting?  Is the `fromEmailAddress` a valid email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one that does not work has the variables reversed, it should be:

```
myMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromEmailAddress, fromDisplayName);
```

Comment: Lol this worked. Thanks Kevin. Didn't realize that I had my variables reversed.